# Analytic function windowing clause

Tags: oracle, analytic-functions

Column VAL is a number list from 1 to 3, the other columns are supposed to show:

- A) MIN of all lower values than VAL
- B) MAX of all lower values than VAL
- C) MIN of all greater values than VAL
- D) MAX of all greater
  values than VAL

I would expect this result:

```
V   A   B   C   D
-------------------
1 |   |   | 2 | 3
2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3
3 | 1 | 2 |   |
```

But the result I get is:

```
V   A   B   C   D
-------------------
1 |   |   | 2 | 3
2 |   |   |   |  
3 |   |   |   |
```

(*) All blank cells are NULL results

The query I wrote:

```
WITH T AS
       (SELECT     CAST(LEVEL AS NUMBER) val
        FROM       DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4)
SELECT   val
        ,MIN(val) OVER(ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND val PRECEDING) A --MIN_PRECEDING
        ,MAX(val) OVER(ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND val PRECEDING) B --MAX_PRECEDING
        ,MIN(val) OVER(ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN val FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) C --MIN_FOLLOWING
        ,MAX(val) OVER(ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN val FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) D --MAX_FOLLOWING
FROM     T
WHERE    val IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
/
```

Does anybody see what's wrong with this query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been wanting to learn more about this.  thanks for the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in `val preceding` and `val following`. It should be `1 preceding` and `1 following`.

The number you specify there is relative to the current record, the record corresponding to val (in the given window order), so if you specify `val` there you are going back (or ahead) too far. You should need to get the min/max up to one record before (or after) the current record.

So:

```
WITH T AS
       (SELECT     CAST(LEVEL AS NUMBER) val
        FROM       DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4)
SELECT   val
        ,MIN(val) OVER(ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) A
        ,MAX(val) OVER(ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) B
        ,MIN(val) OVER(ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) C
        ,MAX(val) OVER(ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) D
FROM     T
WHERE    val IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
/
```